# How to parallelize a function written in cython (Jupyter Notebooks)

Tags: parallel-processing, jupyter-notebook, cython, joblib

I am looking for ways to decrease the computational time of certain tasks. After checking different options, I found that joblib and cython worked best for me in a jupyter environment. However, even though I succeeded in implementing these approaches separately, I failed in combining them.

Below is an example of a sample code that gives the same error message (run in jupyter notebooks):

```
%load_ext Cython
```

```
%%cython
cpdef test(int item):
    cdef int y = 0
    cdef int i
    for i in range(10):
        y += item
    return y
```

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
res = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(test)(i) for i in range(20))
```

**Error Message:** BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.

According to this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), the used variables should be picklable, so I am not sure of the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: I'd suspect it's `test` that it's failing to un-serialize. Does it work if you use a `def` function rather than a `cpdef` function?

Comment: @DavidW I tried it but the error message persists.

Comment: Tentatively I think it's because Cython functions in Jupyter are created in a temporary module. Unpickling then fails because it can't find the module (Cython functions are only pickled as the module and the name). I doubt that there's a good solution but it'd probably work if you used a Cython function defined outside of Jupyter. (Also there's probably more error message than you show: https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/d5c8274f34ab9550d96fcf8761b2e7ab57fb7eb3/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py#L622)

Comment: @DavidW I tried calling for a cython function in joblib using Atom editor and the code run pretty smoothly. So probably you are correct about the cause of the error in Jupyter + Thank you!

Comment: I would like to add that running the code using both cython and joblib appears to have larger computational time than in case of using only joblib.